# How to output text in ukrainian language in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to output ukrainian text in R markdown, but I don`t know how to do it.

I tryed using package"babel", but it didn`t work.
[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYUkZ.png)[enter image description here]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnrNm.png)

Comment: If you are interested in HTML output, you should be able to just include the Ukrainian text in an R Markdown document.  PDF output is harder.  I don't have any experience in Ukrainian, but the issues there are basically getting LaTeX to handle the language and fonts.  You may get better advice on that on a LaTeX forum, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com .